# can AnyOne explain how to properly add constraints to navigation bar buttons or what is wrong with this piece of code?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
navigationBar.items = [navItem]

let searchImage = UIImage(named: "searchIcon")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

let searchButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: searchImage, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleSearch))       
let menubutton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "menu")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(slideMenu))        
let refreshButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "refreshIcon")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleRefresh))

//searchButton.tintColor = UIColor.yellow
// searchButton.t
navigationBar.delegate = self

navItem.setRightBarButtonItems([searchButton,refreshButton], animated: false)
navItem.setLeftBarButton(menubutton, animated: false)
```

[image]

Comment: Your goal is navigation bar placed to top and see menubutton, searchButton, refreshButton?

Comment: You can add UIButton directly drag and drop from storyboard

Comment: Yes, I want to place navigation bar and on left edge menu button and on the right edge search and refresh button should be placed but they aren't placed properly,  and i cant even add constraints to the them to properly adjust the positions.. .

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add navigation buttons to navigation bar is use storyboard. If you decide add button programatically you can reach from ViewController.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems
```

If you have Navigation controller in your Main.storyboard, which is point to your ViewController, then that controller reach top navigation item. Apple leftBarButtonItem documentation say:

> A custom bar button item displayed on the left (or leading) edge of the navigation bar when the receiver is the top navigation item.

So please first check you use top navigation item. 
I offer you work with UIButtons:

```
let leftMenuButton = UIButton(type: .system)
leftMenuButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"your.png"), for: .normal)
leftMenuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.yourFunc(_:)), for: .touchDown)

let searchButton = UIButton(type: .system)
searchButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"yourSearch.png"), for: .normal)
searchButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.yourSearchFunc(_:)), for: .touchDown)

let refreshButton = UIButton(type: .system)
refreshButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"yourRefresh.png"), for: .normal)
refreshButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.yourRefreshFunc(_:)), for: .touchDown)
```

These buttons added to UIBarButtonItem:

```
let menuBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: leftMenuButton)
let searchBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: searchButton)
let refreshBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: refreshButton)
```

In my case added this code under viewDidLoad:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [searchBarItem, refreshBarItem]
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuBarItem
```

For fixing space or add constraint here is [great article](https://www.matrixprojects.net/p/uibarbuttonitem-ios11/)